# How does Python know the datatype of a variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

For example, I am iterating through a dictionary `mydict` as follows:

```
mydict = {"Name" : "Vincent Vega",
          "Profession" : "Gangster",
          "Age" : "42"}

for k in mydict:
    print k, mydict[k]
```

Now, `k` is just a looping variable that I didn't even declare. How does the compiler know that by `k`, I mean the keys of the dictionary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `for` statement use a special method (`__iter__` and `next`) on the object, here `mydict`.

Each iteration produce a result, stored in the variable `k`

For a dictionary, the `__iter__` method returns the keys of the dictionary.

More info [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop).

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop calls `iter()` on the sequence that is looped over, and uses `next()` calls on the result.
 Different objects can return different iterators with different behaviors and that's why at one time you will see it iterate over keys of a dictionary and another time an index of array, depending on the iterable.